# Software Defined Networking (SDN): What is line-speed?

Tags: network, speed, sdn

I can't understand what is meant by line-speed. From a networking point of view, we can say that line-speed is the number of packets transmitted in a unit of time.

I got this term from here:

[link of line-speed term](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.0440.pdf), the paper name is:

Software-Defined Networking: A Comprehensive Survey:

```
Open-source prototypes are available [31] as well as evaluation results showing the line-speed capabilities using a network processing unit (NPU)-based [451] proof of concept implementation.
```

Somebody, please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: It would appear to be used in the context of bandwidth. Basically, how fast can the interface [de]serialize bits on the wire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most often, the terms "line speed" or "wire speed" refer to a device's capability to process or forward data only limited by the respective interface speeds.